# Why does not it show content with the right size directly?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I want to click the button then show an alert view. This alert view will receive two arrays.

The alert view will refresh itself by two UICollectionView layout size.

```
[self.topCollectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.topSelectIndex inSection:0] animated:false scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom];
     
[self.bottomCollectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.bottomSelectIndex inSection:0] animated:false scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom];


 [self layoutIfNeeded];

  CGFloat topFloatHeight = self.topCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height;
  CGFloat bottomFloatHeight = self.bottomCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height;

   self.topCollectionHeightConstrait.constant = topFloatHeight;
    self.bottomCollectionHeightConstraint.constant = bottomFloatHeight;

//    CGFloat bigScrollViewHeight = self.bigScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.heightAnchor
    CGFloat catHeight = topFloatHeight + bottomFloatHeight + 200;
    CGFloat screenHeight = kScreenHeight - 180;
    if( catHeight < screenHeight) {
        self.scrollBoxHeightCont.constant = catHeight;
    }else {
        self.scrollBoxHeightCont.constant = screenHeight;
    }

   self.bigScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, catHeight);

 [self.topCollectionView reloadData];
 
 [self.bottomCollectionView reloadData];
```

As you see, the key code is
 `self.bigScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, catHeight);`

The code change the bigScrollview's contentSize, the alert view always shows right size calculated in above code contents on next time, not this time.

Why does not it show content with the right size directly?
Is where another solution to get the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After collection view reloads with the new data.
Before the customer view  show, add two line code :

[self setNeedsLayout];
[self layoutIfNeeded];

Move the calculate height code into the `layoutSubviews` method.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
[super layoutSubviews];


  CGFloat topFloatHeight = self.topCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height;
  CGFloat bottomFloatHeight = self.bottomCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height;

   self.topCollectionHeightConstrait.constant = topFloatHeight;
    self.bottomCollectionHeightConstraint.constant = bottomFloatHeight;

//    CGFloat bigScrollViewHeight = self.bigScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.heightAnchor
    CGFloat catHeight = topFloatHeight + bottomFloatHeight + 200;
    CGFloat screenHeight = kScreenHeight - 180;
    if( catHeight < screenHeight) {
        self.scrollBoxHeightCont.constant = catHeight;
    }else {
        self.scrollBoxHeightCont.constant = screenHeight;
    }


 self.bigScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, catHeight);
```

}